# PHP MongoDB Upsert Not working

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is my code:

```
  public function insertJob($search = array(), $doc) {
    echo(print_r($doc));
    echo("\n");
    $this->collection->update(
        $search,
        array('$set' => (array)$doc),
        array('upsert' => true)
      );
  }
```

`$search` is set this way:

```
$ft = new FastTrackMongo($arg);

$api = new JobsAPI('API_KEY_HERE');

foreach ($industries as $industry) {
  $jobs = $api->getJobs($industry);
  echo("CALLING API FOR " . $industry . "\n");
  foreach($jobs->job as $job) {
    echo("INSERTING " . $job->title . "\n");

    $job->address = $job->location;
    unset($job->location);

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-d h:i A', $job->dateacquired);
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $job->dateacquired = $date;
    $job->industry = $industry;
    $ft->insertJob(array('jvid' => $job->jvid, 'industry' => $industry), $job);
  }
}
```

For some reason upsert'ing is not working. The script keeps dumping in new records.

Comment: Something is clearly coming though different to the existing documents. Try dumping the $search variable on every request to make sure it is actually what you expect it to be.

Comment: I don't see how $search is set there? But like Neil says... That variable does not contain the data you think it does. But why are you replacing the entire object every time? This is very creepy thing to do and definitely not what you want to be doing in the long run. Only modify the fields that have changed rather then sending the entire object back and forth over the wire as $set. This also affects Replication and object caching...